# Algebraic Closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{Q}(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Defining algebraic closure of $F$ in $E$ as the set of elements in $E$ that are algebraic over $F$, I am trying to understand the following statement from Fraleigh's textbook:

"$\mathbb{Q}$ is the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{Q}(x)$."

From my understanding, I need to show that $\forall \alpha \in \mathbb{Q}(x)$, $\exists f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$, $f(\alpha) = 0$, where $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ is the field of quotients of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. How can this be done? For example, how can I find a polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ that when evaluated on $x^2+1$ equals to zero?

Comment: @ancientmathematician Isn't that what I wrote in the original question? If not, my apologies

Comment: You are misunderstanding the statement. You want to prove that if an element of $f\in \mathbb{Q}(x)$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$, then $f\in\mathbb{Q}$.

In other words, given $f\in\mathbb{Q}(x)$, if there exists a **nonzero** $P\in \mathbb{Q}[T]$ such that $P(f(x))=0$, then $f\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @GreginGre Right, that makes it very clear. Was going in the wrong direction

Comment: @JadenPark I am sorry, I didn't think I had posted that comment, but it got saved by mistake.

Comment: @ancientmathematician no worries :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fraleigh says that the algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb Q(x)$ is $\mathbb Q$. This means that for all rational $\alpha$ there is a non constant polynomial with rational coefficients which kills $\alpha$. This is certainly true, take $f(x) = x - \alpha$. Also it means that these are the only elements of $\mathbb Q(x)$ which are algebraic over $\mathbb Q$. To see that this is true, assume $f/g$ is algebraic over $\mathbb Q$. The ring $\mathbb Q$ is a unique factorization domain, so by dividing out common factors we may assume that $f$ and $g$ are coprime. There is an equation of the form
\begin{align}(f/g)^n + a_{n-1}(f/g)^{n-1}+…+a_0 =0\end{align}
with rational $a_k$. Multiplying this equation by $g^n$ yields
\begin{align}f^n+ a_{n-1}gf^{n-1}+…+a_0 g^n=0\end{align}
which shows that $g$ divides $f$. But since they are coprime, this can only be true if $g$ is a unit. Thus $f/g$ is an element of $\mathbb Q[x]$ which is algebraic over $\mathbb Q$. There are no non-constant polynomials with this property, so we conclude that $f/g$ is a rational number.